# Monte Carlo Tree Search picks bad moves that lose immediately

Tags: tree, artificial-intelligence, montecarlo

I have a working implementation of an MCTS. I am testing it on Tic-Tac-Toe for convenience, but the real target game will be rather larger.

As far as I can tell it generates the correct win counts and explores the tree the way it should, and mostly generates good moves. However, there are situations where the chosen move leads to an immediate loss. Likewise it may not choose a move that leads to a forced win.

My analysis of the win counts is that these are moves where it is actually true that on random play the move will win more than it loses, and the line played by a skilled opponent is not given enough weight.

So the question is how to either (a) tune the MCTS to favour short term wins and avoid short term losses, or (b) add features to the search to that forced lines are detected and prioritised.

Someone who has actually written and completed an MCTS might be best able to answer the question. There are other similar questions on SO and SWE but no helpful answers.

---

To be clear, my implementation of MCTS achieves perfect play on TTT Traffic Lights variant in around 500 iterations, but with 100-200 iterations will sometimes play really bad moves, missing immediate wins or losses. By contrast minimax takes only 81 iterations to avoid bad moves completely (2 ply) but shows general weak play with 729 iterations (3 ply). Anyone with working implementations of these algorithms should see similar results.

MCTS converges to good play, but I'm looking to improve how it performs on sudden death games with low iteration counts. I find Traffic Lights makes a good test bed.

Comment: Have a look at the evaluations of end moves, and detection of win/loss. Is it possible you've got the game value comparison backwardsa on some moves for one of the players? Like, in the opponent's move phase, could you miss a win condition, rendering the move attractive past the endgame? It is a bit hard without code. But MC should *never* play a certain losing move (if there are winning moves!), even 'on average'. The averaging is for training, once training is done the answer is certain. Review game value assessment & game value comparison. Review player order & player goals.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't it. I'm confident of my implementation, and that the possibility of choosing losing moves in sudden death games given a low iteration count is inherent in the algorithm, See edit with more detail. Happy to see someone show otherwise. Hope to publish my code soon.

Comment: During Training Phase, the MCTS should try all actions, including immediate losses. It sounds like it does that? During Testing Phase (after training) it should follow its near-optimal policy and only play good or winning moves. I'm unclear if it does that also? What I start to understand is you simply want to alter move selection and emphasisze some moves over others. If so, have a look at killer heuristic, or maybe evaluate a move's heat based on its WIN-factor. Maybe take inspiration of Q-learning's learning rate?

Comment: Not really. MCTS has no mechanism to prioritise near term wins/losses, so it plays bad near term moves if it does not have enough time for full analysis. I juat want to tweak MCTS to play a better short game, and avoid really those bad moves. I have no idea how to incorporate your suggestions into MCTS unless you can provide links.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this problem?

Comment: @user76284: Sadly, no. I had hoped to find a reference for something like 'tree-pruning in MCTS' to confirm others were aware of the problem and had solved it. I got my code to work, but it's not a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve this same problem. What if your "find moves" code checks for a win for each legal move? If there is an immediate win, return ONLY that move to MCTS--ignore the other technically legal but very bad moves. In this way, instead of pruning bad branches, those bad branches never get added to the tree in the first place. This will probably slow down computation considerably but might be worth it if it's playing more intelligently in the short term.

Comment: Sounds worth a try.